# Create Custom List Item HTML, Row With Spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a project and I want to display something similar to Apple's stocks app, how a single row has a name followed by a current number and then a +- indicator of how much the stock either went up or down from before. I really like this row design against a black background and think its easily readable, so that's why I want to do it. At the moment I am trying to create a single row of HTML combined with CSS that will give me this kind of look and feel, a custom list item if you will.

I have the positive\negative indicators made but cannot figure out how to space and include text to the left of this element within the same list item row. Ideally, the layout should be something like this:

STOCKNAME           PREVTOTAL  STOCKPOSORNEG

All of these fields should be in the same list item row. Since I've had some trouble with this approaching using the un-ordered list I could also explore a table option but wanted to see if there was a way it could possibly be done that way first. Below is what I was experimenting with via the TryIt Editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #rcorners1 {
            border-radius: 7px;
            background: #80ff80;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 90px;
            height: 10px;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        #makeLeft {
            float: left;
        }

        #makeRight {
            float: right;
        }

        #listitem {
            list-style: none;
            background-color: black;
            border: .5px solid #efeff5;
            padding: 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="mylist">
        <li id="listitem">
            <p id="rcorners1">
                <span id="makeLeft"><strong>+</strong></span>
                <span id="makeRight"><strong>1234.00</strong></span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well for starters; you have a lot of things wrong with your markup. Have a look at this fiddle I created for you: https://jsfiddle.net/od7yd7x9/

Comment: Does this help out? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyboGq

Comment: Check my answer out! :) hopefully it will suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work out for you?

I tried to get it as close to the original stocks app as possible. Some of the `font` sizes might be a bit off, but this is probably as good as you're going to get.

```css
span{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}
.container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #040404;
}
.row{
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 29px;
    padding: 13px 10px 13px;
}
.row.highlighted{
    background: #383838;
}
.name{
    float: left;
}
.price{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.pn{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.pn-con{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
.main-pn{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FD3C2F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="name">DOW J</span>
        <div class="pn-con">
            <span class="price">18,109.80</span>
            <div class="main-pn">
                <span class="pn">-</span>  
                <span class="val">53.19</span>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row highlighted">
        <span class="name">MSFT</span>
        <div class="pn-con">
            <span class="price">47.58</span>
            <div class="main-pn">
                <span class="pn">-</span>  
                <span class="val">0.04</span>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/od7yd7x9/4/) for it!

It's pretty customizable, all you need to do is **copy & paste** the `rows`, and alter the values within the `span`s!

Here's an image of the actual stocks app for reference!

[image: Stocks app]

Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I'm looking for and you nailed it to a tee. Simply amazing! As it shows, I need some more practice as CSS, hopefully one day I'll be as good as you. I've created websites before but the CSS and display always takes me the longest, sometimes its more difficult to me than the actual coding part, lol.

Comment: Awesome! @Tastybrownies glad, it helped you! :D don't worry, one day you'll get there ;) just a lot of time and practice. :) have a good day